# Is it possible to make the 3d print add-on module available in sculpt mode?

Tags: add-on, sculpting

Currently I have to frequently switch to edit mode to check for overhangs with the 3d print tool when I am sculpting. Can this add-on be somehow made available in sculpt mode?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the [built in add-on](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/addons/mesh/3d_print_toolbox.html), or a 3rd party add-on?  If the later, which one?  Unfortunately, for the built-in, the answer is 'you'd have to change the source code'.

Comment: @Marty Fouts: Yes the built in add-on. Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make the built in [*3D Print Toolbox*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/addons/mesh/3d_print_toolbox.html) add-on available in any but object and edit modes without modifying its source code.  Here's how to check that for yourself, if you care to read Python code.

- Enable the "Developer Extras" in the *Interface* section of preferences.
- Enable the "3D Print Toolbox" add-on in the *Add-ons* section of preferences.
- Select an object in the scene. In Object or Edit modes, the sidebar will show a tab for the toolbox.

[image: Sidebar open, showing the 3d Print Toolbox]

- Hover over one of the Toolbox buttons and right click.
- Select *Edit Source* from the popup menu

[image: popup right click menu with edit source option]

- The source code for the add-on will appear in the text editor.
- Go to the text editor and look at lines 36-38 of the file, which are

```
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        return obj is not None and obj.type == 'MESH' and obj.mode in {'OBJECT', 'EDIT'}
```

Without going into details, the `poll` function is telling blender that the add-on should only be available if there is an active object and the active object is in object or edit mode.

You could try to change the line, but I suspect you would quickly find the reasons why the developers limited access to those modes.

Comment: ok, thats interesting. I could have a try but am wary about corrupting the source code as Im no python expert :-)

Comment: I didn't go further into the code to see exactly why changing that would be a bad idea but I'm 99+% certain it would be.  Just offered this as an illustration of how to find such things out.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that! Good to know. Many thanks!

Comment: could I talk you into clicking the checkmark on my answer to 'accept' it?  that way people will know that the question has an answer when they look in the future.

Comment: of course, no problem. I had thought I should only checkmark if it specifically/directly answers my question.

Comment: yes.  if you don't feel that it does that, do undo the check, although I thought i had done so.